# Best way to show a list of complex objects and emit event int vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

For sample I have one order that my user can add one store and in each store a lot of itens:

```
Amazon
    - cup    - $ 1
    - notebook  - $ 3
                                   - $ 4   Ebay
    -  bike     - $ 10
    - boat      - $ 13
                                   - $ 23


                          Total order: $ 27  [Button to send the order]
```

And in my project I have 3 components:

CartView -  (show the total from order and a button)
- StoreView (show de Store name, and total)
---StoreitemView (show the item and the button to remove)

lets to the doubts:
1 - The best way to show thats lists are usingo a GRID with one ROW? some like this:

```
Grid<StoreView> myGrid = new Grid();
myGrid.addComponentColumn(this::createStoreView).setAutoWidth(true);
```

or Its best to use a for just like this:

```
  Div myDiv = new Div();
for(Store store in StoreList){
   muDiv.add(new StoreView(store);
}
```

2 - How can I pass event to parent? so when my user click a button at StoreItemView I need to emit that event to my CartView(passing to StorView, and go to CarView to update the values and recreate the cart)

tks

Comment: I am really not sure what layou you want to achieve. Mind drawing it in MS paint and pasting it here?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question so it focuses on the second part and add your attempts or failing code? SO is a Q/A page about concrete programming problems and the first part is primarily opinion based and most likely un-answerable to the question "what is best" -- there are no silver bullets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Layout

The layout depends on how many stores and items you expect. If the number is low, just looping through and adding components is a decent approach.

If you have many items, using a `Grid` with one column is a better approach, as all items aren't rendered at once. An even better approach might be the `IronList`, or since Vaadin 21 the [VirtualList](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/virtual-list).

If your views are complex with a lot of components, it's a good idea to use a `TemplateRenderer` instead of a `ComponentRenderer`. If writing views in HTML instead of Java is not your cup of tea, you can keep on using the `ComponentRenderer`, especially if performance seems to be good.

If there are a lot of items per store, you can consider having a virtual list for the store items inside the store also. Especially if there are only  a few stores.

### Events

There is no correct answer here. It seems like your `StoreView` and `StoreItemView` are tightly coupled, so the communication can be tightly coupled too. For example, the `StoreItemView` can expose the button directly with a `getRemoveButton()` method.

I would use the `ComponentEvent` for the removal event, something like the code below. Your logic for how the `StoreItemView`s are created would be different, and you could add a method in the `StoreView` for adding the event listener. You might want to add some data to the event, too.

```
public class StoreView extends HorizontalLayout {

  public StoreView() {
    // Create your store items as you see fit
    StoreItemView storeItemView = new StoreItemView();
    storeItemView.getRemoveButton().addClickListener(e -> {
      remove(storeItemView);
      fireEvent(new StoreItemRemovedEvent(storeItemView));
    });
    add(storeItemView);
  }

  public static class StoreItemRemovedEvent extends
      ComponentEvent<StoreItemView> {

    public StoreItemRemovedEvent(StoreItemView source) {
      super(source, false);
    }
  }
}
```

```
public class CartView extends VerticalLayout {

  public CartView() {
    StoreView storeView = new StoreView();
    ComponentUtil.addListener(storeView, StoreView.StoreItemRemovedEvent.class, e -> 
        Notification.show("Store item removed"));
    add(storeView);
  }
}
```